# CakePHP beginner - MVC relationship

Tags: cakephp

I'm a beginner in Cake and have gone through the MVC relationship. I've been given the code below to breakdown and I seem not to grasp the hang of it.

```
 <?php echo $html->link($view['User']['nickname'], array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile', $view['User']['nickname'])); ?>
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: what have you read/searched on the Cake Cookbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code given is to generate a `<a href=....>` link inside a View using the HtmlHelper.

In this case, a link is generated to the 'profile' action of the 'users' controller and the 'nickname' of the user is passed as argument. The resulting link will (with a standard route configuration), look like this;

```
<a href='/users/profile/someNickName'>someNickName</a>
```

However, this code is for older versions of CakePHP (1.3 and older), for newer versions, this is the notation;

```
echo $this-Html->link($view['User']['nickname'], array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile', $view['User']['nickname']));
```

Documentation on the HtmlHelper (for CakePHP 1.3) can be found here:

[CakePHP HtmlHelper documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/HTML.html#link)

However, if you're struggling with this kind of questions, I really urge you to read the CakePHP 'CookBook' from the beginning, and preferably start using CakePHP 2.x:

[CakePHP Cookbook - Welcome](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html)

Comment: Hi thaJeztah, I appreciate your answer, it is quite helpful. Having looked at the arguments of the link method, for the the title, what do the values in the square parentheses mean e.g. does it mean ['Model']['nickname']. I've really not understood this bit whereby square brackets are used. It's also repeated at the end of the array elements. Also I'm in the process of reading the CakePHP 'Cookbook' from scratch. Thanks

Comment: When retrieving data via CakePHP models, the data is returned in a multidimensional array, formatted `array('ModelName' => array('fieldname' => 'fieldvalue'))`. So `['User']['nickname']` is the nickname-field of the selected record of the 'User' model.